# OpenCV install stuck on cmake

Tags: linux, raspbian, opencv

I'm currently in the middle of installing openCV3 on my raspberry pi3. The pi is a clean install of NOOBS Raspbian and I'm using this PyImageSearch install guide: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/.

Everything seems good until I get to running cmake to set up the build. The cmake output shows the Python2 filepath with the appropriate library and package path. Python3 shows the filepath through the venv I've set up for the interpretter but no libraries, package path, or numpy filepath.

It's my understanding that the libraries and package paths will show once I get numpy installed locally to the venv but I think it might be? When I try to install in the venv I get: {Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.16.3)}